# Why doesnt my character move python/pygame

Tags: python, pygame

My image does not move up when i press `w`. When i tried to fix it the screen would close sometimes, i am not getting any errors and the screen opens with my character. It just doesn't go up this is python but i don't know which one and i am using **pygame**.

**My code:**

```
import pygame 
pygame.init()

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HIEGHT = 600

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HIEGHT))

player = pygame.image.load('Character.png')
run = 1
while run:
    
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    screen.blit(player,(30, 300))
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
  
    if key[pygame.K_w]:
        (player,(0,-1))
    screen.blit(player,(30, 300))
    pygame.display.flip()
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: The statement `(player,(0,-1))` doesn't do anything useful - it just constructs a tuple, and then throws it away.  I'm not really sure what you intended to do there, since the player image is being blitted at a constant location regardless of what happens elsewhere in the program.

Comment: did you run in console/terminal to see error message? What system do you use: Windows, Linux, Mac? Describe it in question - so more people will see it.

Comment: you have to keep position in variables `x, y` or in more useful `rect = pygame.Rect()` and when you press key then you should change `y -= 1 ` (or `rect.y -= 1`) and later `blit(player,(x, y)` or `blit(player, rect)`

Comment: you should blit player only once in loop.

Comment: use only one: `display.flip()` or `display.update()` - because they do almost the same.

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep position in variables

```
player = ... # load image
x = 30 
y = 300
```

and when you press key then change value in variable

```
if key[pygame.K_w]:
    y -= 1
```

and later use variables to blit it

```
screen.blit(player, (x, y))
```

---

But it can be more useful to use `pygame.Rect()` to keep position and size - because it has also functions to check collisions.

```
player = ... # load image
player_rect = player.get_rect()  # get `rect` with size from image
player_rect.x = 30 
player_rect.y = 300
```

```
if key[pygame.K_w]:
    player_rect.y -= 1
```

```
screen.blit(player, player_rect)
```

```
if player_rect.colliderect(enemy_rect):
   # ... kill player or enemy
```

---

**EDIT:**

Full working code with other changes.
I use `Surface` instead of images - so everyone can simply copy and run it.

You moves green rectangle and you have to catch red rectangle ("apple"). It shows how to check collision. Score is displayed only in console.

```
import pygame
import random

# --- constants ---

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HIEGHT = 600

# --- classes ---

# --- functions ---

# --- main ---
 
# - init -

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HIEGHT))

# - objects -

#player_image = pygame.image.load('Character.png')  # I don't have image
player_image = pygame.Surface((30, 30))             # so I will use green rectangle
player_image.fill('green')

player_rect = player_image.get_rect()
player_rect.x = 30
player_rect.y = 300

apple_image = pygame.Surface((30, 30))   # so I will use red rectangle
apple_image.fill('red')

apple_rect = player_image.get_rect()
# move to random place
apple_rect.x = random.randint(0, SCREEN_WIDTH-30)
apple_rect.y = random.randint(0, SCREEN_HIEGHT-30)

# - gameloop -

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

run = True

score = 0
while run:
    
    # - events - 
        
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    # - updates (without display) -
                
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key[pygame.K_w]:
        player_rect.y -= 5
    if key[pygame.K_s]:
        player_rect.y += 5
    if key[pygame.K_a]:
        player_rect.x -= 5
    if key[pygame.K_d]:
        player_rect.x += 5

    if player_rect.colliderect(apple_rect):
        score += 1
        print('score:', score)
        # move to random place
        apple_rect.x = random.randint(0, SCREEN_WIDTH-30)
        apple_rect.y = random.randint(0, SCREEN_HIEGHT-30)
        
    # - display (without updates) -
    
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    screen.blit(apple_image, apple_rect)
    screen.blit(player_image, player_rect)
    pygame.display.flip()     # needs only one: `flip` or `update`
    #pygame.display.update()  # needs only one: `flip` or `update` 
  
    clock.tick(60) # try to keep 60 FPS on all computers (especially on fast computers)
    
# - end -
pygame.quit()
```